# Show that $M$ is a submonoid of the group of $2\times 2$ matrices of integers mod $13$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modular-arithmetic, monoid

Define

$$M=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix}\in(\Bbb Z/13)_{22}:a_{12}=0\right\}\;.$$

(This is the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with integers mod $13$ with the upper right entry $= 0$.)

(a) Show that $M$ forms a submonoid of $\big((\Bbb Z/13)_{22},\cdot,I_2\big)$.

(b) Determine the order $|M^*|$ of the group $M^*$ of units of $M$.

I'm having trouble with the closure under multiplication part. For example if you multiply two matrices, $A$ and $B$ of the set $M$, then in the first entry, you get $a_{11}b_{11}$, which equals some number $c$. But, this number $c$ is not necessarily an element of the integers mod $13$, $\Bbb Z/13$, is it? So, how is $M$ closed under multiplication?

For the second question, a $2\times 2$ matrix is invertible as long as $ad-bc$ is nonzero, so we just need that $a_{21}$ is nonzero. So, then what would the order be?

Comment: In the notation $(\mathbb Z/13)_{22}$ what does the subscript represent?

Comment: It just means 2X2 matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication takes place in $\Bbb Z/13$: for example, $5\cdot6=4$, since $30\bmod 13=4$. The only thing that you actually have to check is that $(AB)_{12}=0$ whenever $A,B\in M$.

For invertibility be a bit careful:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&0\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_{11}&0\\b_{21}&b_{22}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

if and only if

$$\begin{align*}
a_{11}b_{11}&=1\\
a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21}&=0\\
a_{22}b_{22}&=1\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the arithmetic is all done mod $13$. The first and third equations tell you that the diagonal elements of $A$ and $B$ must be non-zero, and since $13$ is prime, every non-zero element of $\Bbb Z/13$ has a multiplicative inverse. Thus, you can choose $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$ to be any non-zero elements of $\Bbb Z/13$. Doing so will determine $b_{11}$ and $b_{22}$ completely, so the question is then how many solutions the equation $a_{21}b_{11}+a_{22}b_{21}=0$ has for $a_{21}$ and $b_{21}$. Again, remember that you’re working in $\Bbb Z/13$, not in $\Bbb Z$. More generally, if $a$ and $b$ are non-zero elements of $\Bbb Z/13$, how many solutions does $ax+by=0$ have in $\Bbb Z/13$? HINT: multiply the equation by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: The multiplication part makes sense, thanks. Then, you have 12 choices for each of a11 and a22 since they are nonzero. But then for the second part, wouldn't your choice of a22 affect the solution to a21b11 + a22b21 = 0?

Comment: @user115659: Right, so you’re up to $12^2$ possibilities even before you consider the possibilities for $a_{21}$.

Comment: Okay, so for a21, would you have 12^2 possibilities again? Because solving for x in the equation, there is only one option for a-inverse, and then b and y can be any of the 12 integers.

Comment: @user115659: No, $a$ and $b$ are fixed in the equation $ax+by=0$: they’re standing in for $a_{22}$ and $b_{11}$, which are fixed once you’ve picked values for them. (The $x$ and $y$ are standing in for the $a_{21}$ and $b_{21}$ that remain to be determined.) You have $x=-a^{-1}by$, so you can solve for $x$ in terms of $y$; how many choices are possible for $y$?

Comment: Oh, I see. So then can't you just have any of the 12 choices for y?

Comment: @user115659: You can, but you’re missing one choice.

Comment: a21 can be 0, so then y can also be 0, so 13 total choices?

Comment: @user115659: That’s right: for each combination of choices for the diagonal elements you have $13$ for the corner element.

Comment: Okay, so then if the order of the group of units is just all the possibilities of choices that will give you an invertible matrix in M, it would be 157?

Comment: @user115659: No; why are you **adding** $13$?

Comment: or 144*13 = 1872

Comment: @user115659: That’s better. Yes: $12^2\cdot13$.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: @user115659: You’re very welcome.